# Using variables in yml file

Tags: yaml

In a `.yml` file, I have written

```
mine:
    exec_dir: "$GPROOT/bin/release/"
    data_dirs: "$GPROOT/data_dirs/"
    execs:
        - cdf:
            - "XXXXXXX/cdf/0.2M"
```

where `$GPROOT` is defined via a bash variable with `export` in the terminal. What I have written as `XXXXXXX` must be `$GPROOT/data_dirs/`. However, it seems that defining a variable like these

```
- "$data_dirs/cdf/0.2M"
```

or

```
- "{{ data_dirs }}/cdf/0.2M"
```

are incorrect. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can look intro [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html)

```
envsubst < path/to/file.yml
```

Comment: I guess I don't want that. I want to use a variable inside the yml file. That variable doesn't come from bash. The variable which is a path must be defined in the yml file itself.

Comment: you wrote it yourself : `where $GPROOT is defined via a bash variable with export in the terminal`...

Comment: Yes but I said that the problem is the `XXXXXXX` which should be a variable for `data_dirs` inside the file.